# Blazor code colors showing strange behavior in VS

Tags: visual-studio, razor, blazor

I'm having some strange behavior with colors being applied by Visual Studio 2022 (17.8.2) for Blazor syntax:

[image]

Other examples:

[image]

[image]

Any idea what I can do to fix this? FYI: the code runs perfectly ^^

Comment: I didn't reproduce you in my side.. I have 2 ideas here: 1 have a try to restart the computer and reopen your blazor project, 2 upgrade your vs to the latest 17.8.3